# posts_per_page is not working

Tags: wp-query

I have a query to display custom post type categories' posts, but I want to limit the `posts_per_page` to 8, so I am using the code below.
Please tell me, if I'm doing something wrong.

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'cs_album',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'cs_album_categories_tax',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'bollywood-songs'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) :
        $query->the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="wallpaper-box">
            <ul><div class="img-box"><li><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(180,180)); ?><p><?php the_title();?></p></a></li></div></ul>
        </div>
        <?php
    endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: What is your problem? Do you get more than 8 posts? Do you get less ? Are there at least 8 posts of this post type and the tax query restriction? Just two improvements: You don't need to check `if ($query->have_posts())` if you don't do something specific. In this case just the `while` is enough. You don't need to call `wp_reset_query` as you are using `WP_Query`. `wp_reset_postdata` is enough. And **if** you are using `if ($query->have_posts())` you can put the `wp_reset_postdata` inside the `if() { ... }`. You only need to reset the postdata when you actually altered it (by `the_post()`).

Comment: This is a guess, but I'd give it a high chance of being right: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/85657/21376

Answer (score 1):

You could try pre_get_posts in your functions file as another option.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'limit_cpt_tax_term_posts' );

function limit_cpt_tax_term_posts( $query ) {

if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_tax( 'cs_album_categories_tax', 'bollywood-songs' ) ) {

$query->set( 'posts_per_page', '8' );

    }

}
```

You may also find this solution useful as it includes another option and explanation relating to taxonomy terms http://en.bainternet.info/2011/conditional-tag-taxonomy-term-and-its-children