# get_posts not pulling the correct number of posts

Tags: posts, get-posts

I am using the BracketPress plugin and trying to pull all of the posts of post_type `brackets` so I can send a newsletter blast to everyone with their current leaderboard position. However the get_posts that I am using seems to only pull half of the posts I should be pulling. Here's the code I am using.

```
$leaderboard_args = array(
    'meta_key'      =>  'score',
    'orderby'       =>  'meta_value',
    'order'         =>  'DESC',
    'post_type'     =>  'brackets'
);

$leaderboard = get_posts($leaderboard_args);
echo "<!--";
print_r($leaderboard);
echo '-->';
```

If you go to [this link](http://bourbontrailtours.com.mm-dev.net/?page_id=6) and view source you can see the array being outputted. The problem is, in the database there are 10 posts with post_type of `brackets` that have the meta_key `score` so I can't see any reason why they wouldn't be pulled. Even the master bracket (which should have the highest score and thus be pulled first) isn't getting pulled.

I am going to make some edits with more information as I dig through the database and try to figure this out.

Comment: Most probably your posts per page setting for your site is less than 10

Comment: @PieterGoosen Yeah... adding nopaging and posts_per_page to the agrs fixed the issue. If you want to make that an answer I will accept it. Next time instead of immediately jumping into the database and freaking out I should look for the simple solution.

Comment: "sticky" post can contribute to this effect. I don't know if that is the case with your problem. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/85658/21376

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments

> Most probably your posts per page setting for your site is less than 10

One have to remember, `get_posts` uses `WP_Query`. Any new instance of `WP_Query` and the main query (which also uses `WP_Query`) uses the value set for *Blog pages show at most* as default for the `posts_per_page` parameter when this parameter is not explicitly set by the user