# WP_Query custom query showing only 10 posts on all pages

Tags: wp-query

WP_Query custom query showing same only 10 posts on all pages when set to 5. Here is my code:

Updated code:

```
<?php 
global $wp_query;
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array ('pagination'             => true,
'posts_per_page'         => 5,
'ignore_stickie_posts' => true,
'page'               => $paged);

// The Query
$wp_query_new  = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $wp_query_new ->have_posts() ) {
while ( $wp_query_new ->have_posts() ) {
    $wp_query_new ->the_post();
?>  ...<?php 
}
?>
<?php
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

$pages = paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?page=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('page') ),
    'total' => $wp_query_new ->max_num_pages,
    'type'  => 'array',
) );
if( is_array( $pages ) ) {
    $paged = ( get_query_var('page') == 0 ) ? 1 : get_query_var('page');
    echo '<ul class="pagination">';
    foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
            echo "<li>$page</li>";
    }
   echo '</ul>';
    }
   ?>
    <?php } else {

?>
<p><?php _e('Not found, what you are looking for.'); ?></p>
<?php } 

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

One of two things is happening that I can think of:

1. You have sticky posts showing up. Try adding an
   `ignore_stickie_posts` argument.

   ```
   $args = array (
     'pagination'             => true,
     'posts_per_page'         => 5,
     'ignore_stickie_posts' => true,
   );
   ```

   See: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/85658/21376
2. You have a poorly written (too global) `pre_get_posts` filter.
   Something like:

   ```
   function naughty_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
     $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
   }
   add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'naughty_pre_get_posts' );
   ```

Also, when you name your query `$wp_query` you clobber the main query on the page and that can cause unexpected/unpredictable effects. Choose a new name for the custom query, or if you are attempting to alter the main query proper, convert the whole thing into a `pre_get_posts` filter.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I will give it a try and let you know :)

Comment: Hi,Tried to add 'ignore_stickie_posts' => true also changed 'paged' to 'page'. I have updated code in my question. But it dosent seem working.

Comment: also it is showing same 10 posts on all pages even if it is set to show 5 posts.

Comment: So, the other option that there is a bad filter? Did you disable your plugins? Maybe even switch themes?